# Get Order Base Price

Tags: price, fedex

I have the below file that prepares shipping labels for FedEx from Magento:
http://pastebin.com/pWTvAaM1

You can see that on 481 it outputs the order value.  The problem is the value it outputs is in the currency the customer used when checking and not the value in the stores base currency.

How can I make it output the value in the stores base currency (GBP)?

Comment: Take a look at these articles : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852882/magento-convert-order-amount-from-current-currency-to-base-currency, http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-convert-price-from-current-currency-to-base-currency-and-vice-versa/

Comment: I tried the suggestions on those links but unfortunately they don't work and the value doesn't get converted back.

Answer (score 1):

Order totals and taxes are stored twice on the order. Once for the base currency and the other one for the selected currency.

Any column that starts with `base_` will be the base currency and they will have a selected currency column without the `base_` prefix.

In your case I think you want to use `$item->getBasePrice()` and `$item->getPrice()`.